# Как выйти из цикла/функции, если ты в лямбде? С++

Tags: c++

Предположим есть подобная функция:

```
std::expected<int64_t, std::string> foo(/* .... */) 
{
    std::vector<int64_t> approved{};

    for (const auto &value: values)
    {
        // Возвращается expected<int64_t, std::string>
        SomeFunction().map([&approved](int64_t val){approved.push_back(val);})
                      .or_else([]()
                               {
                                   // В случае ошибки нужно вернуть expected
                                   // с таким же сообщением, как и в 
                                   // возвращенном из SomeFunction
                               });
    }
}
```

Как написано в комментарии, мне нужно в случае прихода невалидного Expected сразу же выйти из функции и вернуть из нее такой же невалидный expected с таким же сообщением.

Как это сделать в cpp-way? Понятное дело, что можно нагородить пачку из if-else, но ведь во избежание этого и создан монадический интерфейс у expected, можно ли все таки как-то сделать выход из функции, если я внутри лямбды из or_else?

Comment: Ну, если это именно *исключительная ситуация*... то исключение очень даже подойдет.

Comment: @Harry в том-то и проблема, что ситуация исключительная только в рамках этой функции. Да, я должен завершить выполнение этой функции, но я должен из нее вернуть unexpected. Да и оборачивать в try вызов одной функции - не очень идея, как по мне. Тогда уже лучше boilerplate из if-else

Comment: Это же С-style с возвратом значения.

Comment: @user7860670 что тогда вы предлагаете?

Comment: Предлагаю делать `return` без всяких лямбд, которые в этом примере как раз и являются boilerplate (даже если пытаться запихнуть их в одну строчку).

Comment: Здесь самое место для проверки `if(...) return ...`.  Досрочный выход из цикла, "монадическим" интерфейсом  не предусмотрен.